# Problems with Unity (Launcher?)

Tags: unity, launcher

I am having an issue with (what I believe maybe Unity or Launcher?) but every time I open a terminal, or another program, the minimized applications always shop up under one tab.  So in other words, when I minimize terminator or gedit it goes to my "thunderbird" tab and not the tab its supposed to be going to.  Any ideas and what may fix this problem?

Comment: Have you been using unity tweak tool, tried to install some themes or used compiz setings?

Comment: Nope, I usually dont fool with that stuff because honestly, the only reason I even use GUI is for firefox and thunderbird.  Throughout most of my day I am usually in the terminal working on things.